# Modify udf to display values beyond 99999 in databricks spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, databricks

created a dataset with below schema

```
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Records] = [value: string, RowNo: int]
```

Here value field is fixed length position which I would like to convert it to individual columns and add RowNo as last column using a UDF.

```
def ReadFixWidthFileWithRDD(SrcFileType:String, rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)], inputFileLength: Int = 6): DataFrame = {

    val postapendSchemaRowNo=StructType(Array(StructField("RowNo", StringType, true)))
    val inputLength =List(inputFileLength)

    val FileInfoList = FixWidth_Dictionary.get(SrcFileType).toList
    val fileSchema = FileInfoList(0)._1
    val fileColumnSize = FileInfoList(0)._2
    val fileSchemaWithFileName = StructType(fileSchema++postapendSchemaRowNo)
    val fileColumnSizeWithFileNameLength = fileColumnSize:::inputLength
    val data = rdd

    var retDF = spark.createDataFrame(data.map{ x =>; 
                lsplit(fileColumnSizeWithFileNameLength,x._1+x._2)},fileSchemaWithFileName )
  retDF
}
```

Now in the above function, I want to use a dataset instead of Rdd, as my RowNo is not displaying values beyond 99999.

can someone suggest an alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

I had created a Hashkey and associated sequence number into a dataframe.

The hashkey is also associated with a dataframe as well.

I joined those two after splitting the fixed length position.